# Why is my validation loss lower than my training loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, training-data

Why is my validation loss lower than my training loss? I wonder if those curves are acceptable. I don't know if those curves are true or not.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to be clear what was this training done for ? How was the training done we cant decide anything based on those 2 pictures

Comment: And how did you split the train and validation sets?

Comment: this training was done for epilepsy seizure prediction using keras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case will rarely happen in a real-world dataset, however, it is possible to happen, consider, for example, where the validation data set and the training have roughly the same distribution, with the training set being noisier than the validation dataset, in that case, the learning you are showing is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The general rough reason behind this kind of scenario is that your training set is somehow over-complicated compared to the validation set.

Considering that you used `deep-learning` as a tag, I would even consider the effect of dropout regularization layers. For a theoretical discussion, see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187335/validation-error-less-than-training-error).